# Error running Storm Topologies with mongodb - SimpleMongoLookupMapper.java

Tags: mongodb, apache-storm

when using Apache Storm 2.1.0 with mongodb, I have the error in Bolt execution :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.storm.mongodb.common.mapper.SimpleMongoLookupMapper.toTuple(SimpleMongoLookupMapper.java:46)
    at org.apache.storm.mongodb.bolt.MongoLookupBolt.execute(MongoLookupBolt.java:70)
    at org.apache.storm.executor.bolt.BoltExecutor.tupleActionFn(BoltExecutor.java:234)
    at org.apache.storm.executor.Executor.accept(Executor.java:275)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.JCQueue.consumeImpl(JCQueue.java:131)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.JCQueue.consume(JCQueue.java:111)
    at org.apache.storm.executor.bolt.BoltExecutor$1.call(BoltExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.storm.executor.bolt.BoltExecutor$1.call(BoltExecutor.java:158)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils$1.run(Utils.java:392)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I am using the sample https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/v2.1.0/examples/storm-mongodb-examples
Using  https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v2.1.0/examples/storm-mongodb-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/mongodb/topology/LookupWordCount.java for launching topology

The topology is launched by the command :

```
storm jar --config /tmp/cfg/config.yml storm-mongodb-examples-2.1.4.jar org.apache.storm.mongodb.topology.LookupWordCount mongodb://<user>:<password>@<mongo server address>:<mongo port>/<instance name>?authSource=admin wordcount
```

wordcount is the collection name, that exists in my test.
I get a NPE exception whether the collection exists or not.
Mongodb version is  v3.6.6

Thanks for help

Comment: For mongodb, this came that there were no datas corresponding to the query. Running topology InsertWordCount  solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with HDFS using the sample https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/v2.1.0/examples/storm-hdfs-examples :

```
ava.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils$1.run(Utils.java:407)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.storm.hdfs.spout.FileLock$LogEntry.deserialize(FileLock.java:290)
```

HDFS version is 2.6.0
I happens with the spout unlike mongodb where it is with bolt.